# Как заменить элемент массива на указанное значение?

Tags: c++, массивы

Допустим, я хочу заменить 3 на 2, как это сделать?

```
int mass[size] = { 3, 6, 8, 5, 1 };
```

Comment: Например, `mass[0] = 2;`

Comment: Вы хотите заменить *все* вхождения 3 на 2 или только какое-то одно? Или вам гарантируется, что вхождение всегда единственно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае для замены одного значения на другое во всём массиве (или другом контейнере данных) можно использовать стандартный алгоритм [`std::replace`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int mass[] = { 3, 6, 8, 5, 1 }; 

    for(int v: mass) std::cout << v << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::replace(std::begin(mass), std::end(mass), 3, 2);

    for(int v: mass) std::cout << v << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Результат выполнения](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vnCnxOoyYL0jSdIW):

> ```
> 3 6 8 5 1   
> 2 6 8 5 1
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант

```
int mass[size] = { 3, 6, 8, 5, 1 }; 
mass[0] = 2;
```